# PHP prepared update statement with multiple cols

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, prepared-statement

I'm trying to make my code run a little more smooth but I'm having trouble. I'm trying to update my database that will only ever have 1 row and 15 columns (it's a league table with scores and dates) but the code I'm using is a bit long and could potentially fail drastically. This is my code:

```
  $sql = "UPDATE league SET t1b1='".$t1b1."'";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    $sql = "UPDATE league SET t1c1='".$t1c1."'";}
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    $sql = "UPDATE league SET t1d1='".$t1d1."'";}
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    $sql = "UPDATE league SET t1e1='".$t1e1."'";}
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    $sql = "UPDATE league SET t1f1='".$t1f1."'";}
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    $sql = "UPDATE league SET t1g1='".$t1g1."'";}
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    $sql = "UPDATE league SET t1h1='".$t1h1."'";}
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    $sql = "UPDATE league SET t1b2='".$t1b2."'";}
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    $sql = "UPDATE league SET t1c2='".$t1c2."'";}
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    $sql = "UPDATE league SET t1d2='".$t1d2."'";}
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    $sql = "UPDATE league SET t1e2='".$t1e2."'";}
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    $sql = "UPDATE league SET t1f2='".$t1f2."'";}
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    $sql = "UPDATE league SET t1g2='".$t1g2."'";}
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    $sql = "UPDATE league SET t1h2='".$t1h2."'";}
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}
```

I think this could fail because, for example, if t1b1 though t1h1 work but then t1b2 fails it will only update half of the database which will be irreversible.

I've tried writing a prepared statement so that it runs updates in one query but I can't figure it out. I have found this nice little sample which updates a single entry:

```
public function update($content, $id) {
$stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("UPDATE datadump SET content=? WHERE id=?");
$stmt->bind_param('si', $content, $id);
$stmt->execute();
return $stmt->affected_rows;
}
```

Would it be possible to alter this code so that I can prepare a statement to update all 14 columns with their appropriate variables?

Comment: you can write all the statement in one line.`$sql = "UPDATE league SET t1b1='".$t1b1."', t1c1 = ".$t1c1.",t1d1.....";`

Comment: you mean i could write "UPDATE league SET t1b1=' ".$t1b1." ' t1c1=' ".$t1c1." ' "??

Comment: awesome! i'll give it a go thank you

Comment: yes you can don't forget to add `,` you have missed in above comment.

Comment: `$sql = "UPDATE league SET t1b1='".$t1b1."',t1c1='".$t1c1."',t1d1='".$t1d1."',t1e1='".$t1e1."'";...........`

Comment: This schema is in dire need of a complete overhaul. Try to adhere to the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) of 
[database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) when laying out your data. The column names shouldn't be things like `b1`, `c1` and so on. A database is not a spreadsheet. When you say something like "will only ever have 1 row and 15 columns" that's usually an assumption you'll live to regret.

Comment: You are obviously just starting out and although there is nothing inherently wrong with your idea of making a league table you are actually totally missing out on the power of using databases by building it like this. If instead you had a database table for each team which contained rows for date, score for, score against, points awarded and opponent then you can join the data from those tables to easily create a dynamic league table, you can compare performances against certain teams, you can easily get historic results against each opponent etc etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't recommend using this approach `"UPDATE league SET t1b1='".$t1b1."'";` because if it's user's input you can easly get [SQL injected](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp).

If you only have 15 columns you can create a simple map:

```
$map = [
't1b1' => $t1b1,
't1c1' => $t1c1,
't1d1' => $t1d1,
...
];
```

Then use it to create a placeholder and an array of params:

```
$placeholder = "";
$params = [];
foreach($map as $key=>$val) {
   $placeholder .= ",$key=?";
   $params[] = $val;
}
// Cutting off the first ',' here
$placeholder = substr($placeholder, 1);
```

Then use it in your query:

```
$stmt = $this->mysql->prepare("UPDATE league SET $placeholder");
$stmt->execute($params);
```